# How to deal with big array (100.000 objects)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an array containing 100.000 objects. Those objects have multiple key/value pairs.

Example of my array:

```
var data = [
{
    "name": "John",
    "id": 1,
    "completed": "yes",
    "prio": 3,
    "importance": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Jim",
    "id": 2,
    "completed": "yes",
    "prio": 4,
    "importance": 4
  }
]
```

As shown below I created a new array from the existing one but now with selected key/value pairs from the original array.

```
var newData = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    newData[i] = {"name": data[i].name, "id": data[i].id};

    console.log(newData[1]);

}
```

As you can also see I logged the new array to the console. But what I actually need is to store the array `newData` in a separate file in which I can see all the objects of the array like in my example array `data`. *To be able to see all the objects of `newData` is actually not that important but would be nice for working with the array later on. For example I'd like to use R for better understanding of the data.*

How can I do that?

NOTE: I'm in the browser!

I'm really struggling with that problem and would be glad if someone could help me …

Thanks!

Comment: Are you in the browser or Node.js?

Comment: @JordanRunning I'm in the browser.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server)?

Comment: newData = data.map(i => ({name: i.name, id: i.id}));

Comment: I am not sure what you are actually tryin to achieve? Is this for debugging? Are you trying to have a hosted file with static json? If you are "in the browser" what could you want with a file? What is your end goal here...

Comment: My end goal is to create a data viz. For this I first want to break down my huge array in different arrays.

Comment: What's the point of creating new objects that just have some properties from the original objects? Just use the original objects. It would make more sense if you were selecting specific objects in the new array.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [**URL.createObjectURL()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) along with [**Blob**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) like so:

```js
var TxtFile = function(text) {

  let data = new Blob([text], {
      type: 'text/plain'
    }),
    file = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

  // revoke the URL after you're done using it.
  function _revokeObjectUrl() {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
  }

  return {
    file: file,
    destroy: _revokeObjectUrl
  };
};

const data = [{
    "name": "John",
    "id": 1,
    "completed": "yes",
    "prio": 3,
    "importance": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Jim",
    "id": 2,
    "completed": "yes",
    "prio": 4,
    "importance": 4
  }
];

const newData = data.map(o => ({
  name: o.name,
  id: o.id
}));

document.querySelector('a').href = new TxtFile(JSON.stringify(newData)).file;

//You can still access the array.
console.log(newData);
```

```html
<a download>Download file</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) to store your data and use [this](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)  library to download your file on your device:

```
  var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(newData, null, 2)], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
  saveAs(blob, filename+".json");
```